# The correct usage of "is" vs "was" in the given context

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, compound-complex

Which one is correct:

I have recently completed my degree at the state university, which ***was*** a 4-year course.

or

I have recently completed my degree at the state university, which ***is*** a 4-year course.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatically correct, but mark you as a non-native speaker. (Not a criticism, just a statement.)  I would say, "I recently completed a 4-year degree at Some Random State University."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are good English, but they have slightly different focuses.

The first refers to the work you've completed, while the second refers to the course itself at the state university. The context would determine which is better. If it's for a resume, for example, your intent is to show *you* did the work, so the first sentence is better, whereas if you're promoting your university, you want to focus on programs they offer, so the second makes more sense.